# Cleanest way of filling a disabled input field via DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, orm

I have created a form which allows the user to add to an inventory of items, stored in a database. Each item in the Inventory table is associated with a UID which is auto-incrementing, non-editable, and effectively auto-generated.

The top field in the form is ItemID, which has input disabled and is merely there to inform the user of the ID of the new item they are about to add.

Ideally, here's the pseudo-code:

`<input type="text" name="email" value="<% (SELECT Max(ItemID) FROM dbo.Inventory).ToInt32 + 1 %>" disabled="disabled"/>`

I already have a Linq to SQL ORM set up. This is all being done in MVC, so the idea occurred to me to figure out the correct value inside the form's controller and then just passing it to the view directly.

What would be the cleanest, simplest way to achieve this? I think ideally, the "value" field should be no more than 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work.

If `ItemID` is auto-incrementing field what components increase its value? Anywhere but the database you will run into trouble. Assuming you do use a  database assigned field, when you populate your input field with a value you take the next available value *at that time*. What happens though if two forms are read and submitted out of order? The Id you populate in your value field will not match up with id the database will assign. So this only would potentially work for a single user at a time.

Best is to let the DB assign the value when you do the actual DB insertion using an identity column and not worry about doing this manually or even trying to predict the id - don't populate the value field this way.